# audio.js audio player is not working with angularjs ng-src

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `audio.js` audio player in angularjs. but it is not working properly.
I have different audio Urls which are being passed through `$scope` to `ng-src`.when i click on any audio. it plays the audio. when i stop it and play the another audio. it still plays the previous audio. it seems that modal value is not getting cleared. everytime it will only play that audio which i have played first.

```
<audio ng-src="{{audioUrl}}" preload="false" id="callaudio" />
```

here `audioUrl` remians the very first url and doesn't get changed while clicking on other links.it still plays the same audio.
i chacked the value of `audioUrl` in console. it changed every time when i click on any link.

but in `ng-src={{audioUrl}}` it remains same.

kindly help me.I am breaking my head for last two days.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 < audio>
      <source src = "{{audio.Url}}"type = "{{audio.AudioType}}" >
  < /audio>
```